# OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0

Tags: apache, openssl, php-curl

I am running this piece of code on a Apache server in order to retrieve few zip files.

```
        $ch = curl_init("https://opendata-rncs.inpi.fr/services/diffusion/document/get? 
        listeIdFichier=" . $listFilesId);
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $headers = array(
            "Cookie: " . $token,
            'login: xxxxxxxxxx',
            'password: '. $this->tokenApiInpi,
            "Content-Type: application/json",
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        $raw_file_data = curl_exec($ch);
        
        if(curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

On my local machine it works fine, running on a simple symfony server.

But on the Apache production server, I ve got this error:

> OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F119:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0

Sometimes it works, but it's rare.

> OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

> cURL Information => 7.68.0

curl_getInfo()

```
array:37 [
  "url" => "https://opendata-rncs.inpi.fr/services/diffusion/document/get?listeIdFichier=229514679,230627776,222612310,233647858"
  "content_type" => "application/zip"
  "http_code" => 200
  "header_size" => 705
  "request_size" => 291
  "filetime" => -1
  "ssl_verify_result" => 0
  "redirect_count" => 0
  "total_time" => 0.462636
  "namelookup_time" => 0.003911
  "connect_time" => 0.008549
  "pretransfer_time" => 0.038412
  "size_upload" => 0.0
  "size_download" => 703824.0
  "speed_download" => 1523428.0
  "speed_upload" => 0.0
  "download_content_length" => 5362987.0
  "upload_content_length" => -1.0
  "starttransfer_time" => 0.430148
  "redirect_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_url" => ""
  "primary_ip" => "81.252.220.78"
  "certinfo" => []
  "primary_port" => 443
  "local_ip" => "10.1.2.7"
  "local_port" => 53494
  "http_version" => 2
  "protocol" => 2
  "ssl_verifyresult" => 0
  "scheme" => "HTTPS"
  "appconnect_time_us" => 38371
  "connect_time_us" => 8549
  "namelookup_time_us" => 3911
  "pretransfer_time_us" => 38412
  "redirect_time_us" => 0
  "starttransfer_time_us" => 430148
  "total_time_us" => 462636
]
```

Comment: Is it possible the production server is behind a proxy and it returns an SSL certificate that is not trusted by your application?  Are you able to run curl or openssl command from the production server to see SSL cert that is being returned when accessing opendata-rncs.inpi.fr URL?

Comment: Nop, no proxy. This is funny because it works on local, production  but not in preproduction.